# Losing edit ability for shapefile (converted from delimited text layer)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing

I have been running into a bug with my QGIS 2.16.3 project. It has to do with editing a shapefile after closing the QGIS project and restarting the computer.

So I have a spreadsheet of locations of interest that I plot on my map. I complete this activity by first converting my spreadsheet to a CSV file then adding a new Delimited Text Layer to my project. My spreadsheet has a column for X and Y coordinates so I assign them to the correct field in the "Geometry definition" section. The data points show up in the correct place in my map. After this, I would like this file to be a shapefile so I "Save As" the layer as a shapefile and I am now able to edit the attributes in the file. Everything is fine until I close the project and QGIS program.

When I open the QGIS project up again, my newly created shapefile is still a shapefile, however I have lost the ability to edit the layer. My traditional way around this would to "Save As" it again as a shapefile and I would regain the ability to edit. However, this means I have to copy over all the rules, filters, and layer attributes I assigned to this layer.

Added screenshots

[image: Add delimited text layer]

[image: When I am converting to a shapefile from the delimited text layer file]

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you try and toggle on edit mode and save edits?

Comment: @artwork21 The "Toggle Edit" option is not available when I open the QGIS project again. I receive no errors after editing and saving the shapefile when I am able to edit. FYI, when I first convert the delimited text layer to a shapefile, I just name the source URL and leave everything else default.

Comment: Are you highlighting the shapefile layer name in the layer panel?

Comment: @artwork21 If by highlighting, you mean selecting, yes I did select the layer in the layer panel before right-clicking "Save As". I have tried to replicate the problem and it has less to do with closing the QGIS project and more to do with restarting my computer. Thanks.

Comment: Some screenshots might help us figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: what does it say when you look at the affected Layer using Properties > Metadata > Properties > Capabilities of this layer ?

Comment: @StevenKay "Capabilities of this layer
Create Spatial Index, Create Attribute Indexes, Fast Access to Features at ID"

Comment: It's definitely missing some capabilities. A normal shapefile has "Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Rename Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Create Attribute Indexes, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries." Maybe it's saved in a directory that you don't have permission to edit. Right click on the folder -> properties -> security. Check that you have full control or at least ability to read, write, and modify.

Comment: i vaguely remember seeing a similar question recently, behaviour differs on whether you drag/drop the CSV file in to the layers panel, or add it using the Delimiter Layer button - even when you save to Shapefile. Can't find the question though, but it was showing a similar odd behaviour in capabilities :(

Comment: @StevenKay Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @csk I will try saving locally as opposed to on a server. I did not have "Full Control" rights on the server. Will update.

Answer (score 1):

@csk had the right solution.

> It's definitely missing some capabilities. A normal shapefile has "Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Rename Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Create Attribute Indexes, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries." Maybe it's saved in a directory that you don't have permission to edit. Right click on the folder -> properties -> security. Check that you have full control or at least ability to read, write, and modify.

To resolve my issue, I changed the shapefile location from a server (where I did not have Full Control admin rights) to a local drive.